# Network Cable and Rainy Weather

Tags: networking, cable

How does rain and water effect on network cable such as cat5?

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're having?

Comment: No, i want establish a small LAN and i like to be sure that rain doesn't affect on my connections!

Comment: I can only think you're seriously misunderstanding the meaning of the term "cloud computing". :-/

Comment: If you're running the cable outside, just make sure you're using cable *designed* to be used outside, and run it appropriately.  Otherwise there is basically no chance for weather to impact your networking setup when it's *inside*.

Answer (score 1):

It's just cable. If the insulation keeps the cable dry, then it won't. If it the cable gets wet inside then you risk shorting and so forth. That said, cat 5 is not rated for outside use, so this is a non-discussion, really.